# ant task to print the contents of a directory to a file

Tags: regex, list, ant, build

As part of a custom ant build I'm toying with I'd like to have the build

1. Perform a `<replaceregexp>` on an html document
2. For the 'replace' on the regex, I'd like to iterate a directory of .js files and inject a  tag to point at each file.

I've been looking through the ant docs at
http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html

but I haven't seen anything to help me iterate or list the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to generate the replace text first, by processing the directory containing the .js files.

One approach might be to use a [`fileset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) to gather the names of the files, then a [`pathconvert`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task to construct the html snippet to use a replacement text.  For a directory 'my_dir', for example:

```
<fileset id="dir.contents" dir="my_dir">
    <include name="*.js"/>
</fileset>

<pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="js.html" refid="dir.contents">
  <chainedmapper>
    <mapper type="flatten" />
    <regexpmapper from="(.*)" 
       to='&lt;script type="text/javascript" src="http://your.url/\1"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;' />
  </chainedmapper>
</pathconvert>

<echo>${js.html}</echo>
```

The `flatten` removes the directory part of the file path, leaving just the file name.

The echo then yields something like:

```
 [echo] <script type="text/javascript" src="http://your.url/a.js"></script>
 [echo] <script type="text/javascript" src="http://your.url/b.js"></script>
 [echo] <script type="text/javascript" src="http://your.url/c.js"></script>
```

So, you can then use `${js.html}` as your regexp replace text.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to give this a try and circle back.

Answer (score 0):

The replaceregexp task supports nested fileset element.
Example from task doc

```
<replaceregexp match="\s+" replace=" " flags="g" byline="true">
    <fileset dir="${html.dir}" includes="**/*.html"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html

Is this what you are looking for?